# Issue with CRS in R's writeRaster and SAGA's raster-format

Tags: qgis, raster, r, grass-gis, saga

I have a normal `RasterLayer` in `R` and I would like to write it to a file and visualize it in QGIS. When I look at in in `R` it says:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 3035, 1469, 4458415  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 12.5, 12.5  (x, y)
extent     : 386042.8, 404405.3, 6293348, 6331286  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 2.220446e-16, 0.9845922  (min, max)
```

The I do a `writeRaster(<rasterlayer>, <file.tif>, format = "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)`. When I check the coordinate reference with `gdalsrsinfo` on the command line I get this information:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: no_filter.tif
Size is 1469, 3035
Coordinate System is:
BOUNDCRS[
    SOURCECRS[
        PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 19S",
            BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
                DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                    ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                ID["EPSG",4326]],
            CONVERSION["UTM zone 19S",
```

However, when I drag and drop it to QGIS I get the Unknown CRS output.
Is there anything special that should be considererd when writing raster-files or something like a "best practice"?

**UPDATE**
SO when I just print the raster with
`raster_objects[[1]]` for example I get:

```
> raster_objects[[1]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 3035, 1469, 4458415  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 12.5, 12.5  (x, y)
extent     : 386042.8, 404405.3, 6293348, 6331286  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 2.220446e-16, 0.9845922  (min, max)
```

When I do a `rasterWrite(raster_objects[[1]], "test/test.sdat", format="SAGA")`, I get:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 3035, 1469, 4458415  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 12.5, 12.5  (x, y)
extent     : 386042.8, 404405.3, 6293348, 6331286  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : /home/robin/geodata/hiwijason/workPkg_LslPrd_DEMsmoothing/maipo_basin/data/saga/raster_predictions/test.sgrd 
names      : layer 
values     : 2.220446e-16, 0.9845922  (min, max)
```

And I have no clue why the crs-line is saying NA in the writing-operation

**UPDATE**
Maybe this has to do with the raster beeing in SAGA-Format (`.sdat`)?! Because when I drag and drop the .sdat-file into qgis it gets georeferenced directly. However, when I import it into R and write it out again with:

```
r = raster("...sdat")
writeRaster(r, "...tif", format="GTiff")
```

I lose the crs somewhere on the way. Is there anything I'm doing completely wrong? Would `readGdal` maybe offer help?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem (on Windows10; raster 3.1-5, rgdal 1.5-10, tested in QGIS 3.12.3). Potentially PROJ related issue? [Migration to PROJ6/GDAL3](http://rgdal.r-forge.r-project.org/articles/PROJ6_GDAL3.html)

Comment: Is that the full Coordinate System output from `gdalsrsinfo`? Because it looks horribly truncated - it ends with a dangling comma and lots of closing brackets are missing.

Comment: No no it's not the full output. I just wanted to show, that there  is some output, but in Qgis there is no spatial reference.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. The following method seems to have worked - the coordinate system showed in QGIS as well.

```
theCRS <- sp::CRS('+init=epsg:4283')    # GDA94 (Australia)
crs(theRaster) <- theCRS    
writeRaster(theRaster, ...)
```

The drawback is that you need to know the EPSG code.

If you assign the CRS (this way) to the source data before doing a calculation then the output also seems to have a recognized crs.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this type of issue when importing and write ESA SNAP .dim images in R. Then after some research I tried to update the crs of the raster from [here](https://epsg.io/). It works for me.

try this for your case:

```
crs(raster_objects)<-CRS("+proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

then export your image. you can find the proj4string it [here](https://epsg.io/32719).

Comment: Thank you very much:)! I tried it, but didn't change anything

Comment: I think something is wrong with my data. I tried it with different rasters and it works just normal. Is there any option to check if the metadata of my raster is "valid" ?

Comment: can you share this image with me? or a link? you can find me [Here](https://subhadipdatta007.wixsite.com/profile/contact).